# My Conversion trigger is taking so much time

Tags: trigger, lead-conversion

Currently, I'm working on the parent-child relationship in lead object.
We have a few criteria's while converting a lead

1. We are restricting reps to converting only parent lead.
2. And only the top 20 related leads will be converting as contacts to the same account.
3. And if any related leads are existing we are updating status as not required.

I have updated my code with future apex it's working fine now. But is this the best practice

```
   public class RelatedContacts
{
public Static List<Contact> Relatedcontacts = new List<Contact>();
public static integer count=0;
public Static Set<Id> OtherLeads = new Set<Id>();
public static boolean relatedleads=true;
public static void LeadConvertion(Map<Id,Id> RelatedLeads) 
{
    List<Database.LeadConvert> converts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
    String convertedStatus = [SELECT MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted = TRUE LIMIT 1].MasterLabel;
        for(Lead Lss:[Select id,Parent_Lead__c from lead where Parent_Lead__c=:RelatedLeads.keyset() for update])
        {
            If(Lss.Parent_Lead__c <> null && count <20)
            {
                Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
                lc.setLeadId(Lss.Id);
                lc.setConvertedStatus(convertedStatus);
                lc.setAccountId(RelatedLeads.get(Lss.Parent_Lead__c));
                lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
                converts.add(lc);
                count =count+1;
            }
            if(Lss.Parent_Lead__c <> null && count >=20 && Lss.id != null)
            {
                //Lead lss=new lead();
                //Id ll=new Id();
                //ll.id=Lss.id;
                Count=Count+1;
                //ll.Status='Not Visible';
                //ll.Parent_Lead__c=null;
                OtherLeads.add(Lss.id);
                //OtherLeads.add(lss);
            }    
        }
    Database.convertLead(converts, false);
    If(!OtherLeads.isEmpty())
    {
        UpdateStatus(OtherLeads);
    }
}
@future
Public static void UpdateStatus(Set<Id> updatestatus)
{
    List<Lead> newstatus=new List<Lead>();
    for(Lead statuschange:[select id,status,Parent_Lead__c from Lead where id=:updatestatus])
    {
        Lead l=new Lead();
        l.id=statuschange.id;
        l.Status='Not Visible';
        l.Parent_Lead__c=null;
        newstatus.add(l);
    }
    If(newstatus <> null && !newstatus.isEmpty())
    {
        update newstatus;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Removed the irrelevant salesforce-id tag

Comment: Parent_Lead__c is indexed? Could you ask to Salesforce to create an index...

Comment: N.B. the line `If(newstatus <> null && !newstatus.isEmpty())` is superfluous as newStatus will not be null and update of an empty list does not burn DML

Comment: Does it need to be a future method?  How much time is it taking to convert?  I'm not sure what's the main issue that you're bothered by here

Comment: After I have updated my DML statements under future method is working fine. But just want to make sure if this is the best practice or I need to convert my code